# if file name(just name) comparision shell script

Tags: linux, shell

another newbie in Linux shell scripting.

Basically I've a folder with many files in it. But I need to get only the files that ends with `".log"`

Below is my version which doesn't work

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *;
do
        if [ "$i" == "$i".log ]; then
                echo $i;
        fi
done
```

Could someone please help me on this ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Leaving aside that the string comparison operator in POSIX shell is `=`, not `==`, the condition of your `if` statement looks for filenames that are identical to the name with an additional `.log` appended.  This will obviously never be the case, since every filename will be different after you appended `.log`.

Answer (score 3):

Any reason you can't you can't just do it like this?

```
for fname in *.log
do
    echo $fname
done
```

Comment: Hi John3136. Thanks for the help. Is there a way I can achieve this using if statement ?

Comment: @user2164400: Yes, there are ways to do this using an if-statement, but if what you want is to loop over all `*.log` files, that would be utterly pointless.  If you actually want to do something else, I suggest accepting this answer and asking a new question explaining what you want to achieve and what you have tried – you'll get far more useful answers that way.

Comment: Just for the record, one way of doing this with an if-statement is `if [ -z "${f%%*.log}" ]; then ...; fi`.

Comment: Hi Sven Marnach - That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much. ${f%%*.log} -- what does this mean ? is this a regex ?

Comment: @user2164400: No, it's shell syntax for "remove the longest pattern matching *.log from the variable `f`".  `-z` checks whether what remains is the empty string.  Note that there is _never_ a reason to use this unreadable mess in practice, since the constraint of insisting to use an if-statement when far better alternatives exist isn't a practical one.  Since you didn't tell us what you want to achieve, we won't be able to teach you better options.

Answer (score 0):

@John3136 has the simplest answer. With `bash`, you would use the fact that `==` inside `[[ ... ]]` is actually a *pattern matching* operator, not an equality operator:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *; do
    if [[ "$f" == *.log ]]; then
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs